# How do I record stacktrace of StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-overflow

I've read answers to similar questions about handling StackOverflowException, and I understand that starting from .net 2.0, the StackOverflowException terminates the process, and I'm fine with this.

However, when stack overflow happens, I want to know why it happened, specifically I want to record the stacktrace.

In [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx), it's stated that you can process stackoverflow exception if you set proper attributes to the method:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, this event is not raised for
>   exceptions that corrupt the state of the process, such as stack
>   overflows or access violations, unless the event handler is
>   security-critical and has the
>   HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute attribute.

So I've tried setting `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` to my handler method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        Main(null);
    }

    [SecurityCritical]
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute]
    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject);
    }
}
```

The program still terminates without giving me the stacktrace.

How can I record a stacktrace for StackOverflowException?

Comment: Can you try not running it inside of visual studio. Build a release version and start it from outside visual studio and see if you get the same result.

Comment: When it runs inside VS, it breaks on Stackoverlfowexception. When it doesn't run inside vs, it just crashes without leaving me with a trace